# The Mode After Taking the Reciprocal of Each Datum

Tags: statistics

> Consider a data set with non-zero data $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}.$ It is given that
>   the mean, the mode and the median of the data set are $a$, $b$ and $c$
>   respectively. Determine if it is true that the mean, the mode and the
>   median of the data set $\{\frac{1}{x_1}, \frac{1}{x_2}, \ldots,
>  \frac{1}{x_n}\}$ are $\frac{1}{a}$, $\frac{1}{b}$ and $\frac{1}{c}$
>   respectively.

The mean and median can be easily disproved by counterexamples. For the mode, I am guessing that it is true but I am not sure how to provide a formal proof. Does it have to do with the fact that $$\frac{1}{m} = \frac{1}{n} \iff m=n$$ for any non-zero numbers $m$ and $n$? I would appreciate it if you can provide a proof or an outline of the proof. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It rather depends on what is meant by mode, but if you using something like "most frequently repeated value" then your observation is correct: as you point out this is a bijection and so the most frequently repeated reciprocal must be the reciprocal of the most frequently repeated original value.  But if say you had sampled from a continuous distribution (so almost surely no repeated values) and had attempted to estimate the population mode from the data then it might not be true

Comment: Meanwhile on the median, providing all the values have the same sign and either if there are an odd number of values or you define the median as an interval when there are an even number of values, then I think the statement is true

Comment: @Henry When there are an even number of values, the median is (typically) defined as the average of the 2, not the interval.

Comment: @CalvinLin - I am aware of that, which is why my comment says "you define the median as an interval when there are an even number of values".  It may be convenient to have the median being a single value, but it has little justification and gets more complicated for other quantiles; instead saying "$m$ is a median of the distribution of $X$ when $P(X \le m) \ge \frac12$ and $P(X \ge m) \ge \frac12$" is fairly short and has nice properties under monotonic transformations